# How to access a structure defined in a header file from an implementation file?

Tags: c, struct, header-files

How do you access a struct say `struct common`, that is defined in a header file, in a `.c` file? We'll include the header file in the `.c` file and then can we directly use
`struct common C;`?

header file-new_algo.h

```
      #ifndef NEW_ALGO_H_

       #define NEW_ALGO_H_
       #endif /* NEW_ALGO_H_ */

       struct common{


        float count;
         //other variables

      };
```

main.c

```
 #include "new_algo.h"

  int main()
{
    typedef struct common myStruct;
    myStruct* S;

   S->count = 0;//when I do this segmentation fault occurs
   //this is the error I get in eclipse

/* Thread [1] 0 (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault)   
main() at E:/Namratha//trial/.settings/..\\src\\main.c:44 0x401443*/    

}
```

Comment: The `#endif` in "new_algo.h" should go at the very end. The declarations and/or definitions and/or typedefs ... go between the `#ifndef .../#define ...` pair and the `#endif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, the fault error is not resulted from access control.

Before use struct varible, you should malloc space for it like

`myStrcut *s = (myStrcut *)malloc(sizeof(myStruct))`

then assign:

`s->count = 0`

Please have a try.

Comment: thanks..it hadn't occured to me that I can use sizeof(mystruct) directly. I thought I had to find the size of each variable and then add.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct. Just include the header in the source file and create the instance for the struct.

**header.h**

```
struct common
{
    // ...
};
```

**.c**

```
#include "header.h"
struct common C ;
```

Comment: @Namratha - You can `typedef` the struct and also include header guards for the header file.

Comment: Please check my code. I have edited my question above. I have done all that you've said.

Comment: Oh I think I know the problem. It's because I'm not allocating any memory for the struct. How do I solve this problem. There are too many variables in the struct to calculate the total memory required.